# Redshift STL_LOAD_ERRORS reporting col_length different than DDL

Tags: amazon-redshift

My copy from S3 into Redshift is failing due to "String length exceeds DDL length". Looking at STL_LOAD_ERRORS there are 4 columns that are showing this error.  The col_length is shown as 256 in STL_LOAD_ERRORS, but the DDL clearly shows these columns as varchar(5000).  The records in error have values for these columns in the range of 1000 to 4500 chars, so should fit into the column per the DDL.

Can anyone suggest why the STL_LOAD_ERRORS would show a length of 256 when the DDL says 5000?